# Using gflags library in ubuntu

Tags: linux, gflags

I am having problem installing gflags. If I use apt-get as written in (https://github.com/gflags/gflags/blob/master/INSTALL.md) I get the following error

```
sudo apt-get install gflags
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gflags
```

How can I install gflags?

Answer (score 14):

On Ubuntu or Debian machine You can get related packages doing something like this:

```
$ apt-cache search gflags
```

Output on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04):

> libgflags-dev - commandline flags module for C++ (development files)
>
> libgflags-doc - documentation of gflags
>
> libgflags2 - commandline flags module for C++ (shared library)
>
> python-gflags - Python implementation of the Google command line flags module
>
> python-google-apputils - Google Application Utilities for Python

So, I presume You could install it using it's full name like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgflags2 libgflags-dev
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to add compilation flag when I am compiling a gflag program?

Comment: Using make, CMake, ... or compiling something "by hand"? In general, yes. At least for linkage step.

Comment: At least for Ubuntu 16.04, all that is needed is `$ sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev` as this also will pull in the `libgflags2` dependency automatically.